# Помогите с SQL запросом в C#

Tags: c#, sql

Здрасьте всем. Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться. У меня есть [форма](http://rghost.ru/35566756/image.png). И есть [таблица](http://rghost.ru/35566800/image.png) в БД

Как мне в программе сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Обновить", программа вносила данные в соответствующие поля? Я уже попробовал сделать сам, но не получилось: Вот что я пытался сделать

```
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE Settings SET sitename = '" + "" + "', keywords = '" + textBox2.Text + "', description = '" + textBox3.Text + "', seconds = '" + numericUpDown1.Value + "', domen = '" + textBox1.Text + ");");
```

Comment: 1) пересчитайте кавычки
2) не используйте конкатенацию строк в SQL-запросах - используйте параметризованые запросы

[Работа с подключенным уровнем ADO .NET в C#](http://www.cyberforum.ru/ado-net/thread182279.html)

Answer (score 1):

> domen = '" + textBox1.Text + ");"

Здесь не хватает закрывающей кавычки.
Посмотрите в отладчике как выглядит запрос.

Comment: В каком отладчике?

Comment: В волшебном отладчике, который вы найдете в стране чудес :D

Comment: Предполагал, что в VS есть что-то подобное.
Если ошибся, извиняюсь.

Comment: Он есть, но не по SQL'у...и я не нашел ошибки в SQL, но мой код не работает, что делать? Можно полную версию кода?

Comment: UPDATE MyTable
    Set Field1 = 'dogs', field2 = 'cats'
    WHERE SomeFilter = SomeValue;

у вас такой же код запроса? нет! исправляйте:

    UPDATE Settings 
    SET sitename = 'SomeSiteName', 
        keywords = 'SomeKeyword',
        description = 'SomeDesc',
        seconds = 100500, 
        domen = 'SomeDomen';

Answer (score 0):

Из студийного отладчика
UPDATE Settings SET sitename = '', keywords = 'textbox2', description = 'textbox3', seconds = 'numericUpDown1', domen = 'textbox1); видно, что нехватает закрывающей кавычки. Поэтому корректо будет так:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE Settings SET sitename = '" + "" + "', keywords = '" + textBox2.Text + "', description = '" + textBox3.Text + "', seconds = '" + numericUpDown1.Value + "', domen = '" + textBox1.Text + "');");
```

Comment: У меня теперь другая ошибка...


http://rghost.ru/35574713/image.png

Comment: Видимо, нужно указать, на каком подключении выполняется команда.

Comment: Дак у меня на других командах всё работает, а именно на UPDATE не хочет...

Answer (score 0):

У Вас тут нет подключения к базе. Создайте подключение:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id="+this.user.ToString()+";" +
                                       "password="+this.password.ToString()+";server="+this.server.ToString()+";" +
                                       "Trusted_Connection="+this.Trusted_Connection.ToString()+";" +
                                       "database="+this.database.ToString()+"; " +
                                       "connection timeout="+this.timeout.ToString());
```

Переменные укажите свои.
Потом пишите:

```
        try
        {

            SqlDataReader myReader = null;
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("Ваш запрос к базе", myConnection);
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ee.ToString());

        }
```